# Webcam Stream to CDN FMS

Tags: flash, actionscript, webcam, live

I don't have my own Flash Media Server. I can however use the Highwinds CDN. They run FMS on their CDN. When you schedule a live event, Highwinds gives you two urls: the "server" and "stream name".
Examples:

> server:
> rtmp://fli003.am4.hwcdn.net/XXXX/*definst*
>
> stream name:
> fli/00000-streamname?encoderuser=XXX&encoderpassword=YYY

These two urls can be pasted into the Flash Media Live Encoder application to stream the live event. The respective field names in Flash Media Live Encoder are "FMS URL" and "Stream".

I now have successfully established a connection (I think?) to the FMS server.
The problem: the stream is not showing on the web, and it seems it is not submitted to the CDN.

```
function onStatus(e:NetStatusEvent):void {

trace(e.info.code);

    switch(e.info.code) {

      case "NetConnection.Connect.Success":
        var ns:NetStream = new NetStream(conn);

        ns.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onStatus);

        var camera = Camera.getCamera();
            camera.setLoopback(true);
            camera.setQuality( 0, 100 );
            camera.setMode(640, 480, 25)
        var mic = Microphone.getMicrophone();

        if (camera != null){
            myVid.attachCamera(camera);
            ns.attachCamera(camera);
//            ns.play();
        }
        if (mic != null) {
            ns.attachAudio(mic);
        }
        
        ns.publish("fli/00000-streamname?encoderuser=XXX&encoderpassword=YYY", "live");
        break;
        //...
    }
}

var conn:NetConnection = new NetConnection();



conn.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onStatus);
conn.connect("rtmp://fli003.am4.hwcdn.net/XXXX/_definst_");


//var counter:int = 0;
//conn.onBWDone = function(kbitDown:Number, deltaDown:Number, deltaTime:Number, latency:Number){ };
NetConnection.prototype.onBWDone = function(p_bw) {
   //trace("onBWDone: "+p_bw);
}
NetConnection.prototype.onBWCheck = function() {
   //return ++counter;
}
```

The smil file is there, but I suspect that no data arrives at the server.
The player is only showing a loading animation.

And I now get an additional

> NetStream.Failed
> NetStream.InvalidArg
> NetStream.InvalidArg
> after successfully connecting. No idea where that error came from.

Answer (score 2):

[check the `NetStraem.publish()` reference:](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#publish%28%29)

```
//...
conn = new NetConnection();
conn.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onStatus);
conn.connect('rtmp://fli003.am4.hwcdn.net/XXXX/definst');
//...
private function onStatus(e:NetStatusEvent):void {
    switch(e.info.code) {
        case "NetConnection.Connect.Success":
        ns = new NetStream(conn);
        ns.attachCamera(camera);
        ns.publish("fli/00000-name?encoderuser=XXX&encoderpassword=YYY", "live");
        break;
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this is all very difficult for me. Wouldn't the private method need to be used in the context of a class?

Comment: @ user478419 : if you need to use it in a .fla file - just delete the word 'private' after pasting, and replace 'conn = new NetConnection();' with 'var conn:NetConnection = new NetConnection();' ;)

Comment: Oh, okay. I have changed the code in the original posting to reflect the current status.

Comment: @ user478419 : try to use something like http://code.google.com/p/httpfox/ to find out the exact step that fails

Comment: I have installed this addon. I see GET requests to the webpage that contains the above swf file and the swf file itself. Nothing more.

Comment: @ user478419 : add a trace of `e.info.code` to your `onStatus` function and `ns.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onStatus);` after you create your NetStream

Comment: I added the trace. It shows "NetConnection.Connect.Success". It also complained about ns.play() not having an argument. I have commented that line for now. Is it really necessary? In the documentation, it says I need to attach the camera to the video and play it for the local viewer. It's playing fine locally, so I don't know if I need to call ns.play().

Comment: Without the ns.play(), I get this output: "NetConnection.Connect.Success
NetStream.Publish.Start
". So it seems to be alright? I don't know why nothing is showing in the video player.

Comment: @ user478419 : you don't need `play()` on a publishing stream. the output looks ok. try `ns.publish("fli/00000-streamname?encoderuser=XXX&encoderpassword=YYY");` and `ns.publish("fli/00000-streamname?encoderuser=XXX&encoderpassword=YYY", "record");`

Comment: When I remove the "live", I no longer get a "NetStream.Publish.Start" message. "record" has the same effect as "live" - the player shows a loading animation. Btw, I have confirmed that the stream is working with Adobe Flash Live Encoder. So the problem must be somewhere in the Flash application.

Comment: @ user478419 : it's impossible to continue research without having a complete app. could you share it?

Comment: What you see is the complete app. Or do you mean I should share the stream urls? Here is the fla file for download: http://komasurfer.com/stream.fla

Comment: @ user478419 : got it. i'll take a look

Comment: I was cooking some dinner, so I didn't monitor the stream. But I can see that you checked it out... Christmas lights above the window? Did you get it working from flash?

Comment: @ user478419 : just returned home. i only hit control+enter after downloading so if you've seen the picture it means that unmodified .fla works ok in my flash cs4 on windows 7 home basic. try allowing your local swf to connect the web on http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html or maybe we need to compare some other settings

Comment: Hmmm... okay. It does not work for me locally or on the server. I will ask my host to check the firewall.

Comment: I wanted to do some more testing today. The TCP port 1935 was opened on my server, but still nothing is received. The problem now: I get "NetStream.Failed NetStream.InvalidArg" errors.

Comment: @ user478419 : lol) just started writing a test app for FMIS. i think i'll know more about the subject in a couple of hours

Comment: @ user478419 :did you try to install Flash Media Development Server 4 (a free version with limited clients number) to try your swf on it?

Comment: I am just now revisiting this topic again and have the same difficulties. Why would I need the FMS server? I am not going to install it. I am getting "NetConnection.Connect.Success
NetStream.Failed
NetStream.InvalidArg
NetStream.InvalidArg" now, which is extremely annoying.

Comment: @ user478419 - with the same server side? may i request an FD or flash cs4 compatible example?