# Actionscript class "undefined property" errors

Tags: flash, actionscript

I am having a lot of problems with setting up a webcam connection.
I read that I should use a class for the connection, so that the onBWDone() method is defined and I don't get an error about this method.

The actionscript class:

```
package cam  {
    public class WebcamSetup {

    public var appURL:String;

    public function setConnection():NetStream 

    {
        nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
        nc.client = this;
        nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onNetStatus);
        nc.addEventListener(AsyncErrorEvent.ASYNC_ERROR, onAsyncError);
        nc.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, onSecurityError);
        nc.connect(appURL);

        ns:NetStream = new NetStream(nc);

        return ns;
    }

    public function onBWDone():void{
    }
    }
}
```

In the flash file, I do this:

```
import cam.WebcamSetup;

var wc:WebcamSetup = new WebcamSetup();
wc.appURL = "rtmp://xxxxx";

var nss:NetStream = wc.setConnection();

var camera = Camera.getCamera();

if (camera != null){

    myVid.attachCamera(camera);

    nss.attachCamera(camera);
}
```

I get loads of "undefined method" and "undefined property" errors.
And can I not do a return like this? I get the error "return value must be undefined".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem I see is that your function setConnection has the return type void (which means that the function returns nothing).

```
public function setConnection():void
```

should be

```
public function setConnection():NetStream
```

Then AS3 knows that the object returned from the setConnection function will be of the type NetStream.

It would be useful if you pasted the errors you're getting.

Is getCamera a static function within the Camera class? It's hard to know what's happening.

Comment: Oh, you are right. Now I only get one error: "1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: NetStream." It's on the line that you mentioned ("public function setConnection():NetStream"). The camera call is built in, I think? I do not have a custom class for it.

Comment: You will have to import flash.net.NetStream

Answer (score 0):

[i've answered almost the same question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461054/webcam-stream-to-cdn-fms-from-browser-window/4462375#4462375) (you should wait for NetConnection to connect before creating a NetStream)
 and btw your `nss` and `camera` variables have no type declaration and `var nss = wc.setConnection();` means nothing as long as `setConnection()` returns `void`

Comment: Sorry, I din't see your answer from yesterday. It looks very promising. What would be the correct type for the camera?

Comment: @user478419: `var camera: Camera` :) but i usually do `myVid.attachCamera(Camera.getCamera());`